# How can I specify an Ansible role and its argument in the dependency list of another role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

How can I specify an [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) role and its argument in the [dependency list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#dependencies) of dependent role, both of which are stored in separate Git repositories?

Consider the following incorrect example where role `tomcat` depends on version 8 of role `openjdk`:

```
# Role tomcat at git+http://source/ansible/roles/tomcat.
# File tomcat/meta/main.yml.
---
dependencies:
  # When it retrieves role tomcat, ansible-galaxy retrieves role openjdk. 
  - src: git+http://source/ansible/roles/openjdk
    version: master

  # ansible-playbook invokes role openjdk, but fails to set openjdk_version.
  - { role: openjdk, openjdk_version: 8 }
```

What is the correct way to specify dependency role `openjdk`?

Ansible Galaxy version:

```
derek@derek-lubuntu:~/Projects/deployer$ ansible-galaxy --version
ansible-galaxy 2.3.0 (devel 947e0f264e) last updated 2016/11/10 11:45:16 (GMT -400)
  lib/ansible/modules/core: (detached HEAD 2584fca0ae) last updated 2016/11/04 12:08:44 (GMT -400)
  lib/ansible/modules/extras: (detached HEAD a1dcbf9ce5) last updated 2016/11/04 12:08:44 (GMT -400)
  config file = /home/derek/Projects/deployer/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Ansible Playbook version:

```
ansible-playbook 2.3.0 (devel 947e0f264e) last updated 2016/11/10 11:45:16 (GMT -400)
  lib/ansible/modules/core: (detached HEAD 2584fca0ae) last updated 2016/11/04 12:08:44 (GMT -400)
  lib/ansible/modules/extras: (detached HEAD a1dcbf9ce5) last updated 2016/11/04 12:08:44 (GMT -400)
  config file = /home/derek/Projects/deployer/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Comment: I would set it as a role variable in `var/main.yml`. Does it works for you?

Comment: Btw, accotding to this link: https://galaxy.ansible.com/intro#meta your file is correct

Comment: See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#dependencies which I included in my question.  Neither  `ansible-galaxy` nor `ansible-playbook` complain about the syntax, but `ansible-playbook` ultimately fails complaining that `openjdk_version` is undefined.  I did also think of placing it in `vars/main.yml` as a workaround, though.

Comment: What ansible version do you use? It might be an issue with specific version.

Comment: @AndreyRusanov, I updated my question with Ansible version details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could not find a way to pass `openjdk_version` as an argument to role `openjdk`, I instead followed [Andrey Rusanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755357/andrey-rusanov)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517811/how-can-i-specify-an-ansible-role-and-its-argument-in-the-dependency-list-of-ano#comment68291552_40517811) and added variable `openjdk_version` to `vars/main.yml` of role `tomcat`:

```
---
openjdk_version: 8
```

`meta/main.yml` now contains only the `src` dependency for `openjdk`:

```
# From role tomcat at git+http://source/ansible/roles/tomcat.
# File tomcat/meta/main.yml.
---
dependencies:
  - src: git+http://source/ansible/roles/openjdk
    version: master
```